# Android Button with longer text layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want to have 2 buttons, equal size, with icons on them on the bottom of my Activity layout.
I drew them and everything, but now that I added the icons, one button which has longer text and needs to be written on two lines, insists on being shown 3-5 pixels lower than the other one.
Here is my code:

```
    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Buttonz"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:paddingTop="30dp" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/save36"
                android:text="@string/btn_lbl_confirm" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back36"
                android:text="@string/btn_lbl_cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the result (image)

[image: this is how it looks after adding images to drawableLeft]

As you can see, the buttons are not aligned ...

- If the text in the buttons is short (one line text) then buttons are aligned,
- If on one button the text is on 2 lines while on the other the text is on 1 line, then this alignment occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing and what you want to see?

Comment: try to use layout_weight and sunWeghit attribute in layout

Comment: I edited the question and added the image with the layout, even though you can obtain it very easily by trying the above layout XML in a new project and see it for yourself :). Just add a long text to button one, and a short text to button two. Of course I could make the text in the second button longer so both buttons will be moved ownwards, but why does this happen and how can I prevent it, since this is not really a solution...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `baselineAligned` then two buttons matched

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/Buttonz"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:paddingTop="30dp" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Buttonz"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="hello test \nuser how are you" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="test user" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

work like charm.

Comment: Both answers work. Your answer is second, so I will only mark it as useful since I cannot accept 2 answers. Thank you